# Parsing JSON to Java bean - list remaining null

Tags: json, gson

I'm trying to parse some JSON into a Java Object using GSON. My json is over here: http://ec2-50-112-212-186.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/ske.json

And the following is my Java bean. I created it with the help of [JsonGen](http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/):

```
package ske.entities;

import java.util.List;

public class WordSketch{

    private List<Gramrels> gramrels;
    private String corp_full_name;

    public String getCorp_full_name() {
        return corp_full_name;
    }
    public void setCorp_full_name(String corp_full_name) {
        this.corp_full_name = corp_full_name;
    }
    public List<Gramrels> getGramrels(){
        return this.gramrels;
    }
    public void setGramrels(List<Gramrels> gramrels){
        this.gramrels = gramrels;
    }

    public static class Gramrels {

        private List<Words> words;
        private Number count;
        private String name;
        private Number score;
        private Number seek;

        public List<Words> getWords(){
            return this.words;
        }
        public void setWords(List<Words> words){
            this.words = words;
        }
        public Number getCount(){
            return this.count;
        }
        public void setCount(Number count){
            this.count = count;
        }
        public String getName(){
            return this.name;
        }
        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
        public Number getScore(){
            return this.score;
        }
        public void setScore(Number score){
            this.score = score;
        }
        public Number getSeek(){
            return this.seek;
        }
        public void setSeek(Number seek){
            this.seek = seek;
        }
    }

    public static class Words {
        private Number count;
        private Number id;
        private String lempos;
        private Number score;
        private Number seek;
        private String word;

        public Number getCount(){
            return this.count;
        }
        public void setCount(Number count){
            this.count = count;
        }
        public Number getId(){
            return this.id;
        }
        public void setId(Number id){
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getLempos(){
            return this.lempos;
        }
        public void setLempos(String lempos){
            this.lempos = lempos;
        }
        public Number getScore(){
            return this.score;
        }
        public void setScore(Number score){
            this.score = score;
        }
        public Number getSeek(){
            return this.seek;
        }
        public void setSeek(Number seek){
            this.seek = seek;
        }
        public String getWord(){
            return this.word;
        }
        public void setWord(String word){
            this.word = word;
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I call `WordSketch gramrels = gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()), WordSketch.class);` the `corp_full_name` is filled but `gramrels` is null. What am I doing wrong?

It's my first time using Json so I'm still new to it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is just the name of the field.

In your class the name is "gramrels", but in your JSON response, it is "Gramrels" (uppercase). The name of the variable in your program and in JSON must be the same, because GSON allows you to get from the JSON response only those fields that you're interested in... so if it founds a JSON value in the response that doesn't correspond with any of your class attributes, GSON just ignore that value.

I suggest you to use the annotation `@SerializedName`, in this way:

```
@SerializedName("Gramrels")
private List<Gramrels> gramrels;
```

This way you can keep the name of your attribute in lowercase, following Java naming conventions, but you're telling GSON that the name of this parameter in your JSON response will correspond to "Gramrels"...

You can also do the same with your other variables, for example:

```
@SerializedName("corp_full_name")
private String corpFullName;
```

because `corp_full_name` doesn't follow the Java naming conventions...